# How to display swf file in browser for Liferay vaadin portlet 6.1?

Tags: flash, liferay, vaadin

I have to keep list of swf files in a local directory in my local system, not inside the project folder.

I have to call the swf file from that path using its name and display it in browser for the vaadin portlet in liferay 6.1.

Can anyone please share the thoughts on how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to use Stream Resource .. Just check the below example code..

Best of luck for your visa process :)

```
    Window window = new Window();

    setMainWindow(window);

    Label label = new Label("Embed tag");

    label.setDebugId("lblMsg");


    window.addComponent(label);

    StreamSource s = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

    @Override
    public InputStream getStream() {
    File f = new File("C:/test/test.swf");
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fis;
    }
    };

    StreamResource r = new StreamResource(s,"application/x-shockwave-                        flash",getMainWindow().getApplication());
    Embedded e = new Embedded();
    e.setType(Embedded.TYPE_OBJECT);
    e.setMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
    e.setSource(r);
    e.setWidth("400px");
    e.setHeight("400px");

    window.addComponent(e);
```